# Rename Namespaces programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, rename, visual-studio-macros

I tried this code in visual studio 2010, to rename Namespaces, but his do nothing

```
public void RenameNamespaces()
{
    foreach (EnvDTE.Project aProject in DTE.Solution.Projects) {
        if (aProject.CodeModel != null) {
            foreach (CodeElement elem in aProject.CodeModel.CodeElements) {
                if (elem.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
                    CodeElement2 elm2 = (CodeElement2)elem;
                    elm2.RenameSymbol(GetNewName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I rename Namespaces programmatically?

Comment: You can't in Visual Studio.  Maybe Resharper can help you, though.

Comment: what extacly do you try to do and why?

Comment: I try to obfuscate the source code before I compile it and release Assembly.